# What is the largest cluster of merging galaxies?

Tags: galaxy, universe, galactic-dynamics

Reading about the [Andromeda–Milky Way collision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andromeda%E2%80%93Milky_Way_collision), a galactic collision predicted to occur in about 4.5 billion years between the two galaxies, I went to the galaxy merger page and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy_merger) states that :

> One of the largest galaxy mergers ever observed consisted of four elliptical galaxies in the cluster CL0958+4702.

The universe is a big place and wikipedia is not the most thorough with this subject.

What is the biggest merger we have found up till now?(29-09-2019)

[image]

Galaxy cluster MACS J0717, one of the most complex and distorted galaxy clusters known, is the site of a collision between four clusters. It is located about 5.4 billion light years away from Earth.
<sub>Image credit: X-ray: NASA/CXC/SAO/van Weeren et al.; Optical: NASA/STScI; Radio: NSF/NRAO/VLA</sub>